# supervisorScope cancels its parent

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I was playing around with the supervisorScope in android. The documentation says the following.

> A failure of a child does not cause this scope to fail and does not
> affect its other children, so a custom policy for handling failures of
> its children can be implemented. See SupervisorJob for details. **A
> failure of the scope itself (exception thrown in the block or
> cancellation) fails the scope with all its children, but does not
> cancel parent job.**

But consider the following code

```
viewModelScope.launch {

       launch { someLongJob() }

       supervisorScope {
            launch { jobTwo() }
            launch { jobThree() }
            delay(500)
            throw ArithmeticException()
       }

}

private suspend fun someLongJob() {
    try {
        delay(Long.MAX_VALUE)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Long job cancelled")
    }
}

private suspend fun jobOne() {
    delay(1000)
    throw ArithmeticException()
}

private suspend fun jobTwo() {
    try {
        delay(2000)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Job 2 cancelled")
        throw e
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Job 2 completed successfully")
}

private suspend fun jobThree() {
    try {
        delay(3000)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Job 3 cancelled")
        throw e
    }
    Log.d(TAG, "Job 3 completed successfully")
}
```

It produces the following output

> D/TEST: Job 2 cancelled
>
> D/TEST: Job 3 cancelled
>
> D/TEST: Long job cancelled
>
> ---beginning of crash

My doubt is, as per documentation mentioned in bold, the supervisorScope should not cancel its parent even when the scope itself fails meaning that long job(which is running in the parent job) should not be cancelled. But the output clearly shows that the Long job which runs in the parent also gets cancelled. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`supervisorScope` is a function call just like any other. In your case, it completed abruptly, with an exception. Since you didn't catch it, the same exception caused the `launch` block to complete abruptly, and *that* caused it to be cancelled. Then, following the fundamental principles of structured concurrency, cancellation spread inward and cancelled all the child jobs.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But why does the documention of supervisorScope says that the failure of the scope does not cancel its parent? I can't still understand it.

Comment: The parent in that sentence is your `launch` block and the explanation shows why `supervisorScope` did not cancel its parent job. Put a `try-catch` around it and the `launch`  block is not getting cancelled.

Comment: Yeah! Now I can understand. Thank you

Comment: What's actually confusing is the mentioning of external cancellation in "A failure of the scope itself (exception thrown in the block or **external cancellation**)". When you cancel a scope, you [cancel its job](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/cancel.html). And cancelling a supervisor job [cancels the parent](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-supervisor-job.html). So external cancellation should cancel the parent?

Comment: @shawn Yeah, this area of coroutines is a minefield :) I carefully reread all the involved docs now, and this is my conclusion: `supervisorScope` creates its own `SupervisorJob` and assigns it to the scope. However, this job is _not_ a child of the `Job` existing in the `coroutineContext`. This comes from the same crucial difference I mention in the answer -- `supervisorScope` is just a function call, it does not launch any new coroutines on its own, and thus doesn't need to attach to the surrounding coroutine hierachy.

Comment: After re-reading again the docs and with some testings, I have a different conclusion. **A failure of the scope itself (exception thrown in the block or external cancellation) fails the scope with all its children, but does not cancel parent job** - this actually applies to both supervisorScope and coroutineScope because when it comes to cancelling the parent, it is the parent job type that matters, not the child scope type or child job type. The docs is confusing though.

Comment: For exception thrown, see [this](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/3725).

Comment: For [external cancellation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-job/cancel.html), since it can only be done with CancellationException, it's a normal cancelling and won't cancel the parent. This is just a general behavior: [Failure of a child with an exception **other than CancellationException** immediately cancels its parent and, consequently, all its other children.](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-job/)

Comment: @shawn I don't see any difference between what I and you said :) I introduced a different mental model for the behavior (the scoped `SupervisorJob` isn't a child of the current job in `coroutineContext`), in order to more easily reason about the behavior you describe. `supervisorScope`/`coroutineScope` are just normal functions and exceptions in their body do the same as in any other code. They make the block terminate abruptly, and the exception propagates further up unless it's caught. Unless you explicitly launch coroutines within `supervisorScope`, there aren't any child coroutines.

Comment: I see. So basically supervisorScope/coroutineScope does not have a parent job. Can they have one though? I don't see a way to specify a parent job using these two functions. But then if not, why does the doc have to mention about their [parent cancellation](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/supervisor-scope.html)?

Comment: @Shawn The wording of the docs is not perfectly clear, yes. There's a mismatch between the mental model and the implementation. In the mental model, `coroutieScope` is not the start of any new coroutine, it's just a function call that changes the treatment of coroutines launched within. In the implementation, there is actually a new coroutine, but with no concurrency to the current one.